# (knockout) make the a combobox selection's attribute change a Bonded combobox's option list

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, combobox, subscribe

I have coded a knockout template example that allows to make a selection from a combobox (List One) that will result in the changing of the bounded combobox's (List Two) option list.  The change that should take place is that the newly loaded option list should only contain options that have the same "fieldtype" attribute value as the one selected in the first combobox (List One).

When the page first loads the first load of the second combobox (List Two) looks good but then when first combobox selection changes the second's option list is not changing properly.

here is a fiddle with my code in it: [my code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkhummingbird/c1kqefo6/)

Can anyone give me guides how to make this work?

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/queryBuilder/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/queryBuilder/styles.css" />
<script src="../libs/knockout.js"></script>


<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~MODEL~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<div class="container">
  <div data-bind="with: group">
    <div data-bind="template: templateName"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~group-template~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<script type="text/html" id="group-template">
<br>
The intent of this page is that when <b>List One</b> selection changes <b>List Two</b> options reload with just the options from the get_jsonAttrList() call that have the same "fieldtype" as <b>List One</b>'s selection.
<br>
<br>
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-group" style="border-width: 5px;border-color:blue;">
    List One: 
    <select data-bind="options: attributesAvailable, 
                     optionsText: 'display', 'fieldtype', 
                     selectedOptions: compareAttrObject, 
                     value: compareAttrObject
                    ">
    </select>
    <br>
    List Two:  
    <select data-bind="options: attributesAvailable2(), 
                     optionsText: 'display', 'fieldtype', 
                     selectedOptions: compareToAttrObject, 
                     value: compareToAttrObject
                    ">        
    </select>
  </div>
</script>


<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new QueryBuilder.ViewModel());
  }, true);

function get_jsonAttrList() {
      return [{
          "dbcolumn" : "fid",
          "display" : "id #",
          "fieldtype" : "Number"
        }, {
          "dbcolumn": "fname",
          "display": "first name",
          "fieldtype": "Text"
        }, {
          "dbcolumn": "Apply_d",
          "display": "Application date",
          "fieldtype": "Date"
        }, {
          "dbcolumn": "location",
          "display": "location",
          "fieldtype": "Text"
        }, {
          "dbcolumn": "press_in",
          "display": "press in",
          "fieldtype": "Text"
        }, {
          "dbcolumn": "node1",
          "display": "node count",
          "fieldtype": "Number"
        }, {
          "dbcolumn": "comments",
          "display": "comments",
          "fieldtype": "Text"
        }, {
          "dbcolumn": "reg1_posname",
          "display": "Position Name",
          "fieldtype": "Text"
        }, {
          "dbcolumn": "reg1_inst_",
          "display": "inst count",
          "fieldtype": "Number"
        }, {
          "dbcolumn": "create_d8",
          "display": "create #",
          "fieldtype": "Number"
        }, {
          "dbcolumn": "mapped_d8",
          "display": "mapped #",
          "fieldtype": "Number"
        }, {
          "dbcolumn": "term_d",
          "display": "terminated date",
          "fieldtype": "Date"
        }, {
          "dbcolumn": "start",
          "display": "emp start date",
          "fieldtype": "Date"
        }]
    }


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~group~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    window.QueryBuilder = (function(exports, ko) {
      var Condition = exports.Condition;
      /**
       * creates an instants of the group template.
       */
      function Group() {
        var self = this;
        self.templateName = 'group-template';


        self.compareAttrObject = ko.observable("");
        self.attributesAvailable = ko.observable(get_jsonAttrList());
        self.compareToAttrObject = ko.observable("");
        self.attributesAvailable2 = ko.observable(new Array());

        self.compareAttrObject.subscribe(function() {
          var tempAttrList = get_jsonAttrList();
          if (tempAttrList != null && tempAttrList.length > 0) {
            if (self.compareAttrObject() != undefined && self.compareAttrObject()[0] != null) {
              alert("Length of list two BEFORE list one changed to ["+
                        self.compareAttrObject()[0].fieldtype+
                        "]..." + self.attributesAvailable2().length);

    //fail after firt//                
        self.attributesAvailable2 = ko.observable(new Array());
    //fail after firt//self.attributesAvailable2(new Array());
    //fail all//self.attributesAvailable2.splice(0,self.attributesAvailable2.length);
    //fail after first//while(self.attributesAvailable2.length > 0) {self.attributesAvailable2.pop();}

              for (var i = 0; i < tempAttrList.length; i++) {
                if (tempAttrList[i].fieldtype == self.compareAttrObject()[0].fieldtype) {
                  self.attributesAvailable2().push(tempAttrList[i]);
                }
              }
              alert("Length of list two AFTER list one changed to ["+
                        self.compareAttrObject()[0].fieldtype+
                        "]..." + self.attributesAvailable2().length);
            }
          }
        });


      }
      exports.Group = Group;
      return exports;
    })(window.QueryBuilder || {}, window.ko);

    //~~~~~~~~~~view model~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    window.QueryBuilder = (function(exports, ko) {

      var Group = exports.Group;

      function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.group = ko.observable(new Group());
      }

      exports.ViewModel = ViewModel;
      return exports;

    })(window.QueryBuilder || {}, window.ko);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems confused about whether you're dealing with objects or with arrays. The bootstrap dropdown in your fiddle doesn't appear to allow multi-select so there should only ever be one selected item at a time.

You can remove the "selectedOptions" binding from the select in your template and leave the compareAttrObject(s) as observables. Then you can get rid of all the places you're accessing the objects with an indexer like `compareAttrObject()[0]`.

Your options lists *should* be arrays so those should be declared as `ko.observableArray()` instead of `ko.observable()`.

Finally you need to make sure you're updating your observables instead of replacing them and breaking the bindings. Every time your subscribe fires it's replacing attributesAvailable2 with a new observable array. That should be modifying the existing observable array by removing the existing items and adding only the filtered items back instead.

```js
function get_jsonAttrList() {
  return [{ "dbcolumn" : "fid", "display" : "id #", "fieldtype" : "Number" }, { "dbcolumn": "fname", "display": "first name", "fieldtype": "Text" }, { "dbcolumn": "Apply_d", "display": "Application date", "fieldtype": "Date" }, { "dbcolumn": "location", "display": "location", "fieldtype": "Text" }, { "dbcolumn": "press_in", "display": "press in", "fieldtype": "Text" }, { "dbcolumn": "node1", "display": "node count", "fieldtype": "Number" }, { "dbcolumn": "comments", "display": "comments", "fieldtype": "Text" }, { "dbcolumn": "reg1_posname", "display": "Position Name", "fieldtype": "Text" }, { "dbcolumn": "reg1_inst_", "display": "inst count", "fieldtype": "Number" }, { "dbcolumn": "create_d8", "display": "create #", "fieldtype": "Number" }, { "dbcolumn": "mapped_d8", "display": "mapped #", "fieldtype": "Number" }, { "dbcolumn": "term_d", "display": "terminated date", "fieldtype": "Date" }, { "dbcolumn": "start", "display": "emp start date", "fieldtype": "Date" }] 
}


//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~group~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
window.QueryBuilder = (function(exports, ko) {
  var Condition = exports.Condition;
  /**
   * creates an instants of the group template.
   */
  function Group() {
    var self = this;
    self.templateName = 'group-template';


    self.compareAttrObject = ko.observable();
    self.attributesAvailable = ko.observableArray(get_jsonAttrList());
    self.compareToAttrObject = ko.observable("");
    self.attributesAvailable2 = ko.observableArray(new Array());

    self.compareAttrObject.subscribe(function() {
      var tempAttrList = get_jsonAttrList();
      if (tempAttrList != null && tempAttrList.length > 0) {
        if (self.compareAttrObject() != undefined && self.compareAttrObject() != null) {
          alert("Length of list two BEFORE list one changed to ["+
             self.compareAttrObject().fieldtype+
             "]..." + self.attributesAvailable2().length);
          
       self.attributesAvailable2.removeAll();
          for (var i = 0; i < tempAttrList.length; i++) {
            if (tempAttrList[i].fieldtype == self.compareAttrObject().fieldtype) {
              self.attributesAvailable2.push(tempAttrList[i]);
            }
          }
          alert("Length of list two AFTER list one changed to ["+
             self.compareAttrObject().fieldtype+
             "]..." + self.attributesAvailable2().length);
        }
      }
    });


  }
  exports.Group = Group;
  return exports;
})(window.QueryBuilder || {}, window.ko);

//~~~~~~~~~~view model~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
window.QueryBuilder = (function(exports, ko) {

  var Group = exports.Group;

  function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.group = ko.observable(new Group());
  }

  exports.ViewModel = ViewModel;
  return exports;

})(window.QueryBuilder || {}, window.ko);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~MODEL~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<div class="container">
  <div data-bind="with: group">
    <div data-bind="template: templateName"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~group-template~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<script type="text/html" id="group-template">
<br>
The intent of this page is that when <b>List One</b> selection changes <b>List Two</b> options reload with just the options from the get_jsonAttrList() call that have the same "fieldtype" as <b>List One</b>'s selection.
<br>
<br>
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-group" style="border-width: 5px;border-color:blue;">
    List One: 
    <select data-bind="options: attributesAvailable, 
                     optionsText: 'display', 'fieldtype', 
                     value: compareAttrObject
                    ">
    </select>
    <br>
    List Two:  
    <select data-bind="options: attributesAvailable2(), 
                     optionsText: 'display', 'fieldtype', 
                     value: compareToAttrObject
                    ">        
    </select>
  </div>
</script>


<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new QueryBuilder.ViewModel());
  }, true);

</script>
```

Comment: That worked great.  Thank you for the help and explanation.